# Using Dapper with SQL Spatial Types as a parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, orm, spatial, dapper

I've got a system which basically has to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE @parameter.STIntersects(MyGeometryColumn)
```

This is quite simple to do when using vanilla SQL parameters, you just have to create your parameter in a non-typical way (where the builder variable is a SqlGeometryBuilder which I use to create a rectangle):

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    UdtTypeName = "geometry",
    Value = builder.ConstructedGeometry,
    ParameterName = "@paremeter"
});
```

Now, When I try to do this using dapper, I get an error that it can't figure out how to use this as a parameter. Anyone who has got this working, or any pointers on how to enable this? I do have a workaround, but that involves using the string representation and converting that to a geometry type in my SQL query. I really don't want that.

To answer the comment, the error I'm getting is 'The member Parameter of type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry cannot be used as a parameter value'. In other words, dapper doesn't know how to deal with a SqlGeometry object as a parameter.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key to implementing weird and wonderful DB specific params all boils down to `SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters`

This simple interface has a single endpoint:

```
public interface IDynamicParameters
{
    void AddParameters(IDbCommand command);
}
```

Dapper already has a DB generic implementation of this interface called: `DynamicParameters` which allows you to handle output and return values.

To emulate this spatial stuff I would try something like:

```
public class SpatialParam : SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters
{
    string name; 
    object val;

    public SpatialParam(string name, object val)
    {
       this.name = name; 
       this.val = val;
    }

    public void AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)
    {
       var sqlCommand = (SqlCommand)command;
       sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
       {
          UdtTypeName = "geometry",
          Value = val,
          ParameterName = name
       });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
cnn.Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE @parameter.STIntersects(MyGeometryColumn)",
  new SpatialParam("@parameter", builder.ConstructedGeometry));
```

---

This simple implementation of the interface handles only a single param, but it can easily be extended to handle multiple params, either by passing in from the constructor or adding a helper AddParameter method.

Comment: NOTE: The current version of Dapper (as of me writing this comment) has a slightly different Interface method signature, now => `void AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind modifying Dapper at its core then you can use what I've done... https://gist.github.com/brendanmckenzie/4961483

I modified Dapper to accept `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

- Dapper.EntityFramework 1.26 has support for `DbGeography`
- Dapper 1.32 has inbuilt support for `SqlGeography`
- Dapper 1.33 has inbuilt support for `SqlGeometry`
- Dapper.EntityFramework 1.33 has inbuilt support for `DbGeometry`
- Dapper 1.34 has inbuilt support for `SqlHierarchyId`

So with the latest libraries; it should simply work.