# Mapping SqlGeography with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, mapping, dapper, sqlgeography

I have entity "Point", that contains Id, Text and geography coordinates.

```
CREATE TABLE [Point] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_Point_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Coords] GEOGRAPHY NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertPoint]
    @text NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @coords GEOGRAPHY
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Point](Text, Coords, CreationDate)
    VALUES(@text, @coords, GETUTCDATE())    
    SELECT * FROM [Point] WHERE [Id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

This is ts sql code of table and stored procedure of inserting. I have class for using dapper :

```
public class DapperRequester : IDisposable {
    private readonly SqlConnection _connection;
    private SqlTransaction _transaction;

    public DapperRequester(string connectionString) {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction() {
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public void CommitTransaction() {
        _transaction.Commit();
    }
    public void RollbackTransaction() {
        _transaction.Rollback();
    }

    public void Query(string query, object parameters = null) {
        Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(_connection, query, parameters, transaction: _transaction);
    }

    public void QueryProc(string procName, object parameters = null) {
        Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(_connection, procName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction: _transaction);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Execute<T>(string query, object parameters = null) {
        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<T>(_connection, query, parameters, transaction: _transaction);
    }

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> ExecuteProc(string procName, object parameters = null) {
        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(_connection, procName, parameters,
                                         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction: _transaction);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteProc<T>(string procName, object parameters = null) {
        return Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<T>(_connection, procName, parameters,
                                         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction: _transaction);
    }
}
```

c#-class is :

```
public class Point
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SqlGeography Coords { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And repository has method

```
public Point InsertPoint(string text, SqlGeography coords)
    {
        using (var requester = GetRequester())
        {
            return requester.ExecuteProc<Point>("InsertPoint", new { text, coords }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

When I use such system for any other class, everything is okey, but there is a problem with mapping, I think it is because of SqlGeography type.. Using :

```
SqlGeography coords = new SqlGeography();
        coords = SqlGeography.Point(10.5, 15.5, 4326);
        Point point = new Point { Coords = coords, Text = "Text" };
        point = Repositories.PointRepository.InsertPoint(point.Text, point.Coords);
```

And I have an exception `The member coords of type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography cannot be used as a parameter value`

Is there some secret of mapping that type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dapper 1.32 now [includes direct support for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538154/how-to-use-dapper-with-ms-sql-server-2012-geospatial-sqlgeography-column/25542766?noredirect=1#comment39884016_25542766). Your code should now *simply work*.

Comment: Is it also supposed to work with QueryMultiple? I'm getting "Error parsing column 5" when doing reader.Read. And column 5 is a SqlGeography polygon.

Comment: Be careful to use the right version of SqlGeography depending on which ms database version you are using. I had to install SqlGeography Version 10.5 for Sql 2012. Then it worked fine with Dapper.

Answer (score 1):

Dapper does not support DB Provider specific data types. In your case its GEOGRAPHY.

> Dapper has no DB specific implementation details, it works across all
>   .net ado providers including sqlite, sqlce, firebird, oracle, MySQL
>   and SQL Server

In order to handle this param with Dapper, you would have to write your own handling for it. For an example, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690565/using-dapper-with-sql-spatial-types-as-a-parameter).

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem.  I found that Dapper would map resultant fields to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography` just fine, but using them as parameters didn't work.

I've modified the SqlMapper.cs file to include support for this type.  You can see the Gist here: https://gist.github.com/bmckenzie/4961483

Click on "Revisions" to see what I changed.