# How to use Dapper with MS SQL Server (2012) Geospatial / SQLGeography Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dapper

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with a table that contains a **geography** column and I want to use Dapper in a .Net application working with that database, but as far as I can tell and see in the Dapper code, "only" Entity Framework's DBGeography type is [supported](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.EntityFramework%20NET45/DbGeographyHandler.cs#L29), the underlying SQLGeography data type has no other mentioning in the repository.

Can Dapper handle these column types 'magically' nevertheless or would I have to explicitly write a Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeHandler for these?

Comment: What type(s) are you using currently to map these? Are you using `SqlGeography` directly? or...?

Comment: related; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690565/using-dapper-with-sql-spatial-types-as-a-parameter/25544690#25544690 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090549/mapping-sqlgeography-with-dapper?lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Support for `SqlGeography` has been added in the next release, <s>again via the `Dapper.EntityFramework` package</s>. I haven't built/deployed yet, as I am in two minds as to whether that is the most appropriate assembly for it to live in... but I also don't want to take a dependency on `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` in the core library. There may be a way of doing it without that, though.

---

Update: this has now moved up a level to the core library, so you shouldn't need any EF references or `Dapper.EntityFramework`; it should *just work*; this has been pushed as [Dapper 1.32](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/1.32.0).

Example:

```
public void SqlGeography_SO25538154()
{
    Dapper.SqlMapper.ResetTypeHandlers(); // to show it doesn't depend on any
    connection.Execute("create table #SqlGeo (id int, geo geography)");

    var obj = new HazSqlGeo
    {
        Id = 1,
        Geo = SqlGeography.STLineFromText(
            new SqlChars(new SqlString(
                "LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )")), 4326)
    };
    connection.Execute("insert #SqlGeo(id, geo) values (@Id, @Geo)", obj);
    var row = connection.Query<HazSqlGeo>(
        "select * from #SqlGeo where id=1").SingleOrDefault();
    row.IsNotNull();
    row.Id.IsEqualTo(1);
    row.Geo.IsNotNull();
}

class HazSqlGeo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SqlGeography Geo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking/hoping for - thanks Marc!

Comment: @JörgB. let me know if you get any problems, etc

Comment: Will do - going to give this a thorough try later today.

Comment: @JörgB. note: 1.34 supercedes this and includes geometry and hierarchyid support

Comment: When using 1.34 inserting works perfectly fine (I can see it in SSMS), however I cannot retrieve the entry - I get a System.Data.DataException (see https://gist.github.com/jbattermann/07308bda78f12645e9e2). Sample app / data looks like this: https://gist.github.com/jbattermann/ab4a436c669714e4561b. I've referenced Dapper (1.34) & and the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package but that exception complains about a 10.0.0 & 11.0.0 assembly mismatch. Sql Server in this case is SQL Express 2014. Is that dapper related or something else going on?

Comment: @Jorg have you tried an assembly binding redirect from 10 to 11? You can look inthe app.config of the dapper unit test project for an example.

Comment: Binding redirect.. oh my, forgot about that one - but it worked! \o/

Comment: I had the 10.0.0 and 11.0.0 issue as well, with the nuget package. The reason is that Dapper seems to use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll from the MS Sql Server SDK, while the NuGet package adds a 2nd copy to your system. Simply removing the nuget package and adding a reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll instead fixed this for me.

Comment: I'm "using Dapper" but I don't see a SqlGeography type. What namespace is this in? I pulled Dapper down from nuget. I'm running the latest stable version: 1.42.0

Comment: I think I just found it in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Comment: @MarcGravell is there special handling for dot net core 5.0? I am unable to resolve SqlGeography type using the Dapper package.

Comment: @loopy78 not currently; if you have a knowledge of what is required for this on .NET 5 etc: a PR would be welcome

Comment: @MarcGravell the following implementation provides a workaround https://gist.github.com/bricelam/7eca234674c3ca4150872f899af37611