# Cannot use SqlGeography as parameter with Dapper and ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, dapper

I'm trying to insert a **'geography'** datatype in SQL Server using Dapper 1.50.2 with ASP.NET Core 2.1.

I've read on several threads that it should be [accepted by default since 1.32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538154/how-to-use-dapper-with-ms-sql-server-2012-geospatial-sqlgeography-column), yet I receive an exception when trying to insert the data type.

Note: I'm using a **non .NET CORE** data type in my entity. `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types: 14.0.1016.290` since I couldn't find a good .NET core compatible geography datatype. [(something with EF Core)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1100)

Entity:

```
public class Address : Entity{
    /* .. */
    public SqlGeography SpatialLocation { get; set; }
    /* .. */
}
```

Insert method (standard):

```
public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity entity){
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.CreationUser)){
        entity.CreationUser = "UNKNOWN";
    }

    if (entity.EndDate == default(DateTime)){
        entity.EndDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
    }

    return (TEntity) DapperExtensionsProxy.Insert(entity);
}
```

Insert method (specialized):

```
public override Address Insert(Address entity){
    if (entity == null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    }

    var sql = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Address]"
                  + "([CreationDate]"
                  + ",[StartDate]"
                  + ",[UpdateDate]"
                  + ",[EndDate]"
                  + ",[CreationUser]"
                  + ",[UpdateUser]"
                  + ",[CityId]"
                  + ",[Street]"
                  + ",[Street2]"
                  + ",[SpatialLocation]"
                  + ",[Flags])"
              + "VALUES"
                  + "(@creationDate"
                  + ",@startDate"
                  + ",@endDate"
                  + ",@creationUser"
                  + ",@cityId"
                  + ",@street"
                  + ",@street2"
                  + ",@spatial"
                  + ",@flags);";        

    DapperExtensionsProxy.Execute(sql, new
    {
        creationDate = entity.CreationDate,
        startDate = entity.StartDate,
        endDate = entity.EndDate,
        creationUser = entity.CreationUser,
        cityId = entity.CityId,
        street = entity.Street,
        street2 = entity.Street2,
        flags = entity.Flags,
        spatial = entity.SpatialLocation
    });

    /* should get ID back, check with SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() */

    return entity;
}
```

I've also tried the Dynamic parameters approach with dapper (from the first post) but I'm unsure how to apply them together with different parameters

**Exception**

```
The member spatial of type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography cannot be 
used as a parameter value
```

***UPDATE***

I've solved this through a work-around with this piece of code. Getting the syntax right proved difficult.

```
public override Address Insert(Address entity){
    if (entity == null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    }

    var sql = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Address]"
              + "([CreationDate]"
              + ",[StartDate]"
              + ",[EndDate]"
              + ",[CreationUser]"
              + ",[CityId]"
              + ",[Street]"
              + ",[Street2]"
              + ",[SpatialLocation]"
              + ",[Flags])"
              + "VALUES"
              + "(@creationDate"
              + ",@startDate"
              + ",@endDate"
              + ",@creationUser"
              + ",@cityId"
              + ",@street"
              + ",@street2"
              + ",@spatial "
              + ",@flags); "
              + "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    string lat = entity.SpatialLocation.Lat.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string longitude = entity.SpatialLocation.Long.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    entity.Id = DapperExtensionsProxy.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql,new{
                                                             creationDate = entity.CreationDate,
                                                             startDate = entity.StartDate,
                                                             endDate = entity.EndDate,
                                                             creationUser = entity.CreationUser,
                                                             cityId = entity.CityId,
                                                             street = entity.Street,
                                                             street2 = entity.Street2,
                                                             flags = entity.Flags,
                                                             spatial = $"POINT({lat} {longitude} 4326)"
                                                         });
    return entity;
}
```