# Dapper Spatial Geography Type

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial, dapper

I'm cooking up some spatial examples and have decided to give Dapper a go, although EF has spatial support, and I'm loving having control over my SQL again (Thanks Sam & Marc).

However, I need to be able to have POCO's that support the *DbGeography* class. For example :

```
public class BuriedTreasure {
   public int PirateId { get; set; }
   public DbGeography MarksTheSpot { get; set; }
}
```

My Google foo has been letting me down and the closest match I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690565/using-dapper-with-sql-spatial-types-as-a-parameter) question, though it only caters for adding spatial support as a parameter (so it's 50% there).

Now as far as I can see I'm limited to the following options of which neither to me is a viable solution.

1. Customize the dapper code to understand a SQL Server specific type
2. Specify LONG, LAT & ELEVATION decimals in my POCO and create the SPATIAL type in my stored procedure and have another procedure to retrieve the values (or use a persisted computed column but that's nearly the same)

Alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, essentially I went for option 2 in the question I posted above. I have my spatial data mapped to decimals. The stored procedure does some additional checking so it was easy to construct the point therein, ie the following snippet :

```
Yarrrr = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)
```

Essentially, the DbGeography class is immutable, goes to show... RTFM :)

No changes to dapper required at all!